# how to select particular column from relationship collection table in laravel mongodb jessenger

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I have 3 columns in my database. 2 columns is connected with one column by using a hybrid relationship.
here is my query.

```
$data=Client::with('product','department')->select(['product.product_name','product.product_description']);
```

how to select row from another table?

Comment: are you getting any error...?

Answer (score 0):

in your `product` or `department` relation method do the selection with all the forging keys if you have any other relation for product for later use is you want them like

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany(department::class)->select(['id', 'another_relation_to_product_id', 'product_name', 'product_description']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way

```
$data = Client::with(['product:id,product_name,product_description','department'])->get();
```

see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads in **Eager Loading Specific Columns** section. Or you can do it

```
App\User::with([
    'product' => function ($query) {
         $query->select('id', 'product_name', 'product_description');
    },
    'department'    
])->get();
```